# How to use a custom login screen with Apache Kerberos Authentication

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, kerberos

I have configured Apache for Kerberos Authentication using Windows 2012 Server.  The configuration file from Apache is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    ServerName myapp.example.com
    <Location />
            AuthType Kerberos
            AuthName "Kerberos Authentication"
            KrbAuthRealms srv1.test.com
            KrbServiceName HTTP/myapp.example.com@srv1.test.com
            Krb5Keytab /etc/httpd/conf.d/http.keytab
            KrbMethodNegotiate On
            KrbMethodK5Passwd On
            KrbSaveCredentials On
            KrbVerifyKDC off
            Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

It shows a Kerberos Authentication login screen and I can logon correctly by providing the username and password.

The login screen shown is a Basic Authentication login screen.  I am working on a Web Application that has its own security module built in Perl CGI that does authentication from Active Directory. Is it possible that the login screen shown by Apache Basic Authentication can be changed to use a custom login screen that is integrated in my Web Application? Are there any CPAN modules available so that I can integrate Kerberos Authentication in Perl CGI instead of doing it in Apache?